# Android-DirectionalViewPager: NoClassDefFoundError: com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager$DataSetObserver

Tags: android, android-layout

I get this error when I try to incorporate [Android-DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) into a new project:

```
-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 13:04:03.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1526): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager$DataSetObserver
```

Here're logs from View designer:

> com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager failed to instantiate.
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter$DataSetObserver
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(ProjectClassLoader.java:242)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:76)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
>         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
>         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:338)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:170)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:321)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:331)
>         at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:683)
>         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1267)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1061)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2746)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1433)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
>         at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
>         at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>         at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>         at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
>         at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
>
> ```
> eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
> java.version=1.7.0_07
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
> BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
> Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
> Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
> ```

Any suggestions ?

P.S. I've included the library and support one.

Comment: did you fix your issue...i am facing the same problem

Comment: no, I had to rewrite the original view class http://about-midnight.com/?p=64. Cautions though, I haven't had time to rinse and clear

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem, the reason is that the android-support-v4.jar library used by DirectionalViewPager library being older version and making it not compatible with currently using version for development. Maybe you can use the below library for replacement.
https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

In addition, you can also refer to the below link might be helpful.
[Error including Android-DirectionalViewPager .jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse)