# Vertical Viewpager on newest Android Support Library gives Errors

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, swipeview

I am using the [VerticalViewpager by Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) but it gives Errors with the newest Android Support Library:

```
package android.support.v4.view;

public final class VerticalViewPagerCompat {
private VerticalViewPagerCompat() {}

  public interface DataSetObserver extends PagerAdapter.DataSetObserver {}

  public static void setDataSetObserver(PagerAdapter adapter, DataSetObserver observer) {
    adapter.setDataSetObserver(observer);
  }
}
```

The Error is "PagerAdapter.DataSetObserver cannot be resolved to a type". The newest support libraries have changed the behaviour of DataSetObserver and the Vertical Viewpager does not work anymore. Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Comment: HI. Did you managed to fix this issue ?thanks

Comment: Nope, sorry I did not, we started using the viewFlip library and there was no need for this feature anymore

Comment: Check this out, appearantly they fixed it! Untested though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse/14268702#14268702