# DirectionalViewPager ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'am using [DirectionalViewPage](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)r from library [android-directionalviewpager-1.2.1fixed.jar](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24363935/android-directionalviewpager-1.2.1fixed.jar) with android.support.v4 (r11).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
   <android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run application I have errors:

E/AndroidRuntime(15335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.w/com.example.w.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: **Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager**
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1654)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1670)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335): **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager**
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at com.example.w.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(15335): **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.w-2.apk]**
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime(15335):    ... 20 more

What I do wrong?
I read [this quation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse), but not get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem, the reason is that the android-support-v4.jar library used by DirectionalViewPager library being older version and making it not compatible with currently using version for development. Maybe you can use the below library for replacement.
https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager

In addition, you can also refer to the below link might be helpful.

[Error including Android-DirectionalViewPager .jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you!!! I putted everywhere one version of the support library, and it's work!

Answer (score 0):

It's because this class is not a part of support library.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

You have an instruction how to use it here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager

Comment: It's not work. I get very same exception.
Yes? I read instruction. But I use android.support.v4 **r11**. I only include android-directionalviewpager-1.2.1fixed.jar to my project.

Comment: You should add this entire library. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project you have instruction how to do this.

If it works for r4 that means that in this library is probably used support library v4, try to update support library in this lib.

RightClick on your lib project and go to Android->AddSupportLibrary. It should get latest version.

Comment: This what I did:
1. Created new project in android.
2. Put android-directionalviewpager-1.2.1fixed.jar to library/target and add jar to project.
Than

Comment: 3. Create android existing project (library from github)

Comment: After running a get exception:[2013-02-06 01:44:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
[2013-02-06 01:44:40 - w] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;

Comment: I update support library in the lib and get error in java classes.