# setDataObserver and newest support library

Tags: android

my app uses DirectionalViewPager library which has own support-library-v4.jar but when I use this version, when I press home button it causes force close. I found that I should change to the newest version of support library but then, DirectionalViewPager can't import: PagerAdapter.DataSetObserver

How can I fix that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the scope may have changed causing the DVP library to not work.  See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19110) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720276/error-including-android-directionalviewpager-jar-in-eclipse/14268702#14268702) for more details and work arounds.

Add the following class to your project(Make sure to have the package correctly otherwise this won't work):

```
package android.support.v4.view;

    public final class PagerAdapterPublicCompat {
        private PagerAdapterPublicCompat() {}

        public interface DataSetObserver extends PagerAdapter.DataSetObserver {}

        public static void setDataSetObserver(PagerAdapter adapter, DataSetObserver observer) {
            adapter.setDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }
```

then you have to set your data observer:

```
// from the sample code:
final DirectionalViewPager pager = (DirectionalViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
// new addition:
PagerAdapterPublicCompat.setDataSetObserver(pager.getAdapter(), YourDataSetObserver);
```

Comment: When I use the .jar from the second link app does not work. And I don't know what I can get from the first one to fix app.

Comment: Which version of the DVP library are you using?

Comment: It's 1.2.1, the newest possible

Comment: Yours class `PagerAdapterPublicCompat` is equal to `VerticalViewPagerCompat` which is currently in the library and what is `YourDataSetObserver`? I don't use any DataSetObserver.

Comment: Ahh. I misunderstood.  I thought you were trying to and couldn't. I think they moved the DataSetObserver to android.database.DataSetObserver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html.

Comment: Maybe because my poor English. Sorry :) I've seen that DataSetObserver is moved but I don't know who to make it works. Any advice?

Comment: Finally, the jar from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14268702/1356669 is the sollution. I've forgotten to change from `com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager` to `android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager` in my xml.