# Crash when trying to use DirectionalViewPager (by Jake Wharton)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I looked through all questions on stack overflow with similar problem, but haven't managed to find solution, that suites my case.

I need to implement following structure:
Fragment A is being replaced with fragment B. Fragment B contains ViewPager, that switches fragments C1 and C2. This works great if I use ViewPager from support library, but the problem is, that I need a ViewPager to use vertical swipe. For that purpose I'm using library by Jake Wharton from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268702/1220743.

Some code:

**A is being replaced by B**

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
String tag = this.getClass().getName();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(tag).commit();
```

**B initializes DirectionalViewPager**

```
DirectionalViewPager viewPager = (DirectionalViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(fm));
```

This gives me crash when A switches to B, with following crash stack:

```
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1450)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager.populate(DirectionalViewPager.java:399)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.view.DirectionalViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(DirectionalViewPager.java:550)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13029)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2683)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3778)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3610)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3555)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3531)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
08-18 16:47:02.320: E/AndroidRuntime(29610):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone faced similar problems?

Comment: use New version of Support Library v4 (or Android 4.2 may be it will help you

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm already using it, so it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find the solution to this?  are the two fragments already in a fragment?  if so use getChildFragmentManager()  whats curious to me is that getFragmentManager makes it look like you are not using support v4 or it would be getSupportFragmentManager no?  but by the log, it seems the error is happening when you use the support lib.