# Processing in Eclipse - Java Access Error when using ControlP5

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to run a Processing sketch in Eclispe which uses the wonderful ControlP5 library. The sketch runs without problem in the Processing IDE. Yet the line

```
controlP5 = new ControlP5(this);
```

throws the following error when i run it from eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field processing.core.PFont$Glyph.value from class controlP5.BitFont
    at controlP5.BitFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.ControlP5.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at basic_controls.setup(basic_controls.java:46)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1579)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7076502/1641381

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Thanks to your comment I just realized that the eclipse plugin uses a rather Processing version (1.xy) and is not actively developed anymore. Uh