# what is the relationship between tomcat and jdk and web application?

Tags: java, tomcat

Here is the question I asked recently: [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt.md5Crypt function. exception occured under linux, but fine under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449400/org-apache-commons-codec-digest-md5crypt-md5crypt-function-exception-occured-un)

Although finally, I resolved it, but I'm still confused. What made this happen?

My jdk was 1.7, my tomcat was 7, my web application was compiled by jdk 1.7, version of commons-codec.jar was 1.10, then an exception was thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.getMd5Digest()Ljava/security/MessageDigest; from class org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Md5Crypt
```

When I changed my tomcat from 7 to 8, it worked fine. Why? What does tomcat do to applications?

Comment: are you sure both tomcat were using Java 7 ?

Comment: yes, i'm sure about this. both tomcats are using JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest that the problem was not resolved because you used tomcat 8 instead of 7, but it was resolved because you had a conflict in your java build path meaning that you had two different versions of the `commons-codec` JAR at run time probably had one in your tomcat 7 lib folder.

Comment: You can check your previous build path to confirm or refute my claims!

Comment: I've checked that before! I'm using maven to manage jars, I'm sure there is only one commons-codec jar. and the tomcat was new downloaded.

Comment: You were right, I found a different commons-codec was included by a third party jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder, and it's not managed by maven, so I can't found that through maven dependence. I deleted this ugly jar file, it works fine. now I can say "I resolve this problem", right? thank you!