# "Exception in Application start method" in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a simple JavaFX application. Unfortunately each time I run it, I am receiving: `Exception in Application start method`.

I have 2 classes, `Counter` and `Main`. In addition, I am currently using IntelliJ.

Here is my code:

**Main.Java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        Counter ctr = new Counter();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        btn.setText("Start thread");
        btn.setOnAction(ae -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                ctr.increase();
                Platform.runLater(() -> lbl.setText("Value: " + ctr.getCounter());
            });

            t.start();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(lbl);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Counter.java**

```
package sample;

public class Counter {
    private int counter = 0;
    private boolean IsMoreWork = false;

    public synchronized void increase() {
        if (IsMoreWork) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        counter++;
        IsMoreWork = true;
    }

    public synchronized int getCounter() {
        IsMoreWork = false;
        notify();

        return counter;
    }
}
```

**Exception in Application start method**

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x5f2050f6) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x5f2050f6
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463251/java-illegalaccessorerror-superclass-access-check-failed

Comment: Which is line 21 of class Main?

Comment: JavaFX uses modules; have modules been setup in your IDE?

Comment: One mistake you are probably making is `import java.awt.*;`. You should not be suing `awt` unless it's 100% necessary.

Comment: Where is `module-info.java`?

Comment: Start here -> https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.

Comment: @NomadMaker line 21 is Button btn = new Button();

Comment: I think I haven't setup the JavaFx modules

Comment: @Sedrick I guess `module-info.java` doesn't exist because I haven't setup the modules

Comment: java naming conventions, please ..

Comment: The duplicate is "when creating Label" whereas your error likely occurs "when creating Button", but both the source of the problem and the solution is the same.