# Selenium with Java modules

Tags: java, selenium, java-module

I have a pretty simple code using selenium (sample from https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/):

```
package core;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {

    private static final String pathChromeDriver = "chromedriver.exe";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathChromeDriver);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        try {
            driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3")));
            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine (except that the 'main' not terminating, but the question is not about that).

Now I'm trying to make the project modular, so adding `module-info.java`:

```
module test {
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.api;
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver;
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.support;
}
```

Not sure if it is important, but I'm using **java 16** and **maven**, `dependencies` for selenium (version 4.0.0-alpha-5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And now execution fails with exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver (in module org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver) cannot access class org.openqa.selenium.internal.FindsByXPath (in module org.seleniumhq.selenium.api) because module org.seleniumhq.selenium.api does not export org.openqa.selenium.internal to module org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at test/core.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please change your complier to java8 for testing purpose and try again?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463251/java-illegalaccessorerror-superclass-access-check-failed

Comment: @WaqarNadir but java8 does not support java modules