# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while using spring batch to get the list of executions

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am Getting this error when trying to run spring batch to load the list of executions.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.getJobParameters(Ljava/lang/Long;)Lorg/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters;
>   from class
>   org.springframework.batch.admin.service.JdbcSearchableJobExecutionDao

After doing some analysis, I found that JdbcJobExecutionDao is part of Spring-batch and has the implementation of getJobParameters() as protected method while, JdbcSearchableJobExecutionDao is part of spring-batch-admin which has extended the JdbcJobExecutionDao.

So as per the Oracle documentation, it says that IllegalAccessError is -

> Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field or to
>   call a method that it does not have access to.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only
>   occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly
>   changed.

I don't understand, I don't have control over these jars/classes. Am I doing something wrong while using them? or is there a problem with the versions I am using for both jars.

spring-batch - version 2.2.0.RELEASE

spring-batch-admin - version 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT(Tried with 1.3.0.RELEASE also)

Refered to sites -
[java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076414/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcJobExecutionDao.java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/service/JdbcSearchableJobExecutionDao.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by using proper versions. It was a version mismatch problem between spring-batch & spring-batch-admin. I referred to this spring docs site and tried the recommended versions and it worked!

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/spring-batch-admin-manager/dependencies.html

So, now I am using

> 2.2.7.RELEASE(Spring-Batch)

with

> 1.3.1.RELEASE(Spring-Batch-Admin)

and I am not getting the `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` anymore. Need to check if any other functionalities have been disturbed because this is a very old project.

Hope this helps someone facing similar problem.