# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop:()

Tags: android, android-support-library

The following crash increased from one release to the other, once we switched from generating a release build from a windows machine to a Mac OS X machine. It happens primarily with Android 4 (90% + )

Any help is appreciated.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop:()V from class xx.com.app.view.orderflow.OrderActivity
       at xx.com.app.view.orderflow.OrderActivity.onReallyStop(OrderActivity.java)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:668)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleMessage(FragmentActivity.java:87)
```

Comment: Have a look into [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076414/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help me much