# While initiating the ChromeDriver getting below exceptions

Tags: java, selenium

I'm very new to Selenium. Below given is my first test script.

```
package package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tutorials1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 String exepath="C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exepath);
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("inpUserId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("inpPassword")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogonLabel")).click();

}
```

}

While executing the above code I am getting below exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.start(ChromeDriverService.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.execute(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:46)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:415)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
    at package1.Tutorials1.main(Tutorials1.java:12)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 17780
Only local connections are allowed.
```

NOTE : Also tried executing the same script from Internet Explorer also, still getting the same. It just opens the browser and closes(because of finally block) it.

Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: Change your exe path to appropriate and if you still have issue, then this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076414/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method) might be a break through

Comment: chrome driver version , chrome browser version ?

Comment: Tried but no success.

Comment: ChromeDriver version : 2.35.528161
Chrome Browser version : Version 65.0.3325.162

Comment: I ran your code and it's successfully execute. So may be there is an issue in your chromedriver and selenium jar file version. Check it both version once.
Check here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: @Shivangi use Double Back Slash (\\) in your path before chromedriver.exe

Comment: @Hiten, but I am not getting the output. Can you tell me the reason.

Comment: @Shivangi you need to download the 2.37 chrome version which supports the 64-66 chrome. Your current chrome version supports 62-64 chrome browser.
Download from here :: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

Comment: Hi Hiten, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi Hiten, Its working now. Thanks. 
I have one more question, can you please tell me can I link Jquery code with java code ? If yes, then how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got same error 5 days back after some research I got to know my chrome driver version is not compatible with the selenium version so I just upgraded my **chromedriver.exe** file version and everything works perfectly.

Comment: and kindly change this l;ine -->"C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe to --> "C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe ths

Comment: Hey Shubham, can you tell me which version did you upgrade it to ?

Comment: verison 3.12 of selenium and chrome driver 2.35.0 but before doing that change your  diver location path format i have mentioned it and try to run if again you get this error then go for upgradation

Comment: I upgraded the chrome driver version and made the changes specified by you but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Update you guava.jar file i forgot to mention earlier.

Comment: Tried all ways suggested by you but no success

Comment: what is your selenium version,guava.jar and chrome version?

Comment: Chrome Browser version : Version 65.0.3325.162
Selenium version : 2.0.7.0

Comment: Hi Shubham, It's working now. Thanks'

Comment: How you solved it?

Comment: I just created a new project and ran the same code again and it worked.

Comment: I have one more question, can you please tell me can I link Jquery code with java code ? If yes, then how to do it ?

Comment: http://www.doublecloud.org/2012/12/developing-web-application-with-jquery-and-java-servlet/ hope this helps

Comment: No. it didn't help.

Comment: Actually, I have written a Jquery code to download the files from the above site but I don't know how to link it with HTML. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Sorry no experience in that