# Flink streaming application IllegalAccessError when I tried to run application

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to the flink ecosystem and I started working on Hello world flink streaming with the following code snippets. In my opionion the streaming execution environment seems the reasons for the exception. I can not get a solution for a similar problem.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
DataStreamSource<String> stream = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000);
        
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> sum = stream.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
    .keyBy(0)
    .sum(1);

sum.print();

env.execute("Java word Count Example");
```

The following is the error code generated

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.flink.core.execution.DefaultExecutorServiceLoader.<init>()V from class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
....
....
...
at myflink.SocketTextStreamWordCount.main(SocketTextStreamWordCount.java:16)
```

did anyone faced the same problem. Any helps are appreciated

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Did you try one of the supported?

Comment: I am using JDK 8

Comment: I look forward for your help if you have similar experience

Comment: It might be different java versions to compile and run or other stuff described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/7076414/2096986

Comment: Could you please provide your `pom.xml` / `build.gradle` file and specify the way you launch the application ? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I managed the problem. The problem was with flink core version. I changed the flink core version, and now it is smoothly running

Comment: [Sumeet K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107449) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67015867) saying "Use jdk 1.8 in intellij ide, worked for me."